# JQuery animation and mouse hover

Tags: jquery, image, animation, hover

I am trying to make a search bar appear next to an image when you hover over it, and disappear when you hover over the image next to it. I have basically gotten it working, but it is acting really glitchy. It's hard to explain in writing how it is behaving, but you can see what I'm talking about here: http://thecampusbubble.com/redesign/sandbox/problem.php. I think a big part of the problem occurs when you hover over one image, then quickly go to the next one before the search bar has completely appeared.

Here is my code:

```
<div class='header'>
<div class='pageContainer'>
    <img class='bubbleLogo' src='    ../lib/images/bubbleLogo.png    ' />
    <div class='iconContainer' id='findContainer'>
        <div class='headerIcon findIcon' id='find'></div>
        <div class='searchBar' id='findSearchBar'>
            <div class='innerBox'>Night Life</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='iconContainer' id='buzzContainer'>
        <div class='headerIcon buzzIcon' id='buzz'></div>
        <div class='searchBar' id='buzzSearchBar'>
            <div class='innerBox'>Night Life</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='iconContainer' id='feedContainer'>
        <div class='headerIcon feedIcon' id='feed'></div>
        <div class='searchBar' id='feedSearchBar'>
            <div class='innerBox'>Night Life</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$('#find').hover(function(){
    $('#findSearchBar').animate({opacity: 100, width: 290}, 500);
    $('#findContainer').animate({width: 365}, 500);

    $('#buzzSearchBar').animate({opacity: 0, width: 0}, 500);
    $('#buzzContainer').animate({width: 79}, 500);

    $('#feedSearchBar').animate({opacity: 0, width: 0}, 500);
    $('#feedContainer').animate({width: 79}, 500);
});
$('#buzz').hover(function(){
    $('#findSearchBar').animate({opacity: 0, width: 0}, 500);
    $('#findContainer').animate({width: 79}, 500);

    $('#buzzSearchBar').animate({opacity: 100, width: 290}, 500);
    $('#buzzContainer').animate({width: 365}, 500);

    $('#feedSearchBar').animate({opacity: 0, width: 0}, 500);
    $('#feedContainer').animate({width: 79}, 500);
});
$('#feed').hover(function(){
    $('#findSearchBar').animate({opacity: 0, width: 0}, 500);
    $('#findContainer').animate({width: 79}, 500);

    $('#buzzSearchBar').animate({opacity: 0, width: 0}, 500);
    $('#buzzContainer').animate({width: 79}, 500);

    $('#feedSearchBar').animate({opacity: 100, width: 290}, 500);
    $('#feedContainer').animate({width: 365}, 500);
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#buzzSearchBar').animate({ opacity: 0, width: 0 }, 0);
    $('#feedSearchBar').animate({ opacity: 0, width: 0 }, 0);
    $('#buzzContainer').animate({ width: 79 }, 0);
    $('#feedContainer').animate({ width: 79 }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If i have understood what the problem is you may want to try using [queues](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/)

I suppose you want an animation to stop immediately when you hover to another element. You can do that using .clearQueue

Comment: That worked, thanks! I don't have enough rep to up vote you, but that was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @user1270558, did it for you... +1